# Play framework template automatically imports models._ among other things

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

It seems like in Play framework templates,

there is an implicit "@import models._" and "@import play.api.data.Form" because my code:

```
@(title: String)(myForm: Form[User])

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    ....
</html>
```

works without having to put explicit import statements after the first line. This issue has been raised in the past: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/7FT68jd5asU/xYF0VNySJYcJ

What other classes/objects are implicitly imported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, Play Framework automatically add some `import` statements to all templates.

You can find these "default imports" in the `PlaySettings` trait from Play source code : https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala

If you need to, you can add some additional imports in the project settings defined in your Build.scala :

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings( 
    templatesImport += "com.acme._"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Play 2.3 I use this line in `build.sbt`

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports ++= Seq("very.long.package._", "another.package._")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the file : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L40

All those mentioned there are imported.

Additionally, `templatesImport += "com.acme._"` is enough in 2.2.X to import all the files from a package i.e. in the file `build.sbt`.