# Play exception: '{' expected but 'import' found

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

It throws me the exception for line 3. The thing is i have just these lines:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import views._
import models._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Ok(views.html.index("grrr", "blabla"))

}
```

EDIT: index.scala.html

```
@import helper._

@main("Todo") {

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

}
```

I'm using play 2.2.0 on windows xp (with sbt)

Comment: Where (line number, file) does the error indicate that the problem is to be found? It could be in places other than your controller.

Comment: The error comes from the file i displayed, the controller.application file

Comment: Your `Application` code seems to be correct. Can you show the `index.scala.html` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that problem is with yours line separator in IDE. I once change LF(Linux) to CR(Mac)(by mistake, not knowing that this has an impact on compilation) and struggle with the same problem. After changing to default sperator everything back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

The first line in Play! template is reserved for the signature definition. This is also mentioned in the `Welcome` screen when you create a new Play Application.

Beside the question why you import the `helper._`, I would do the following:

1. Make the first line empty, or at least *NO* import statements.
2. Run `play clean`
3. After this it should work, I hope :-)

Further information:

- [Play framework template automatically imports models._ among other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397215/play-framework-template-automatically-imports-models-among-other-things)
- https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/1acfd1dc4264e7589876fb1f4ebf37e584ab8bc6/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html#L81
- If you know a bit scala (I don't yet): https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/src/templates-compiler/src/main/scala/play/templates/ScalaTemplateCompiler.scala

**EDIT: 2013.09.24 at 22:15**

You are passing two arguments to your view template (`views.html.index("grrr", "blabla")`), (views are compiled to functions). So in your function (`index view') the first line *SHOULD* define the function signature (arguments). I think that you should write your template as:

```
@(firstString : String, secondString : String)

@import helper._

@main("Todo") {

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

}
```

Comment: The problem stays. By the way, i'm not using the play command, just straight sbt.